# Groupby on categorical column with date and period producing unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas

The issue below was created in Python 2.7.11 with Pandas 0.17.1

When grouping a categorical column with both a period and date column, unexpected rows appear in the grouping.  Is this a Pandas bug, or could it be something else?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2015-12-29', '2016-1-3'), 
                   'val1': [1] * 6, 
                   'val2': range(6), 
                   'cat1': ['a', 'b', 'c'] * 2, 
                   'cat2': ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 2})
df['cat1'] = df.cat1.astype('category')
df['month'] = [d.to_period('M') for d in df.date]
>>> df
  cat1 cat2       date  val1  val2   month
0    a    A 2015-12-29     1     0 2015-12
1    b    B 2015-12-30     1     1 2015-12
2    c    C 2015-12-31     1     2 2015-12
3    a    A 2016-01-01     1     3 2016-01
4    b    B 2016-01-02     1     4 2016-01
5    c    C 2016-01-03     1     5 2016-01
```

Grouping the month and date with a regular series (e.g. `cat2`) works as expected:

```
>>> df.groupby(['month', 'date', 'cat2']).sum().unstack()
                   val1         val2        
cat2                  A   B   C    A   B   C
month   date                                
2015-12 2015-12-29    1 NaN NaN    0 NaN NaN
        2015-12-30  NaN   1 NaN  NaN   1 NaN
        2015-12-31  NaN NaN   1  NaN NaN   2
2016-01 2016-01-01    1 NaN NaN    3 NaN NaN
        2016-01-02  NaN   1 NaN  NaN   4 NaN
        2016-01-03  NaN NaN   1  NaN NaN   5
```

But grouping on a categorical produces unexpected results. You'll notice in the index that the extra dates do not correspond to the grouped month.

```
>>> df.groupby(['month', 'date', 'cat1']).sum().unstack()
                   val1         val2        
cat1                  a   b   c    a   b   c
month   date                                
2015-12 2015-12-29    1 NaN NaN    0 NaN NaN
        2015-12-30  NaN   1 NaN  NaN   1 NaN
        2015-12-31  NaN NaN   1  NaN NaN   2
        2016-01-01  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN  # <<< Extraneous row.
        2016-01-02  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN  # <<< Extraneous row.
        2016-01-03  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN  # <<< Extraneous row.
2016-01 2015-12-29  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN  # <<< Extraneous row.
        2015-12-30  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN  # <<< Extraneous row.
        2015-12-31  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN  # <<< Extraneous row.
        2016-01-01    1 NaN NaN    3 NaN NaN
        2016-01-02  NaN   1 NaN  NaN   4 NaN
        2016-01-03  NaN NaN   1  NaN NaN   5
```

Grouping the categorical by month periods or dates works fine, but not when both are combined as in the example above.

```
>>> df.groupby(['month', 'cat1']).sum().unstack()
        val1       val2      
cat1       a  b  c    a  b  c
month                        
2015-12    1  1  1    0  1  2
2016-01    1  1  1    3  4  5

>>> df.groupby(['date', 'cat1']).sum().unstack() 
           val1         val2        
cat1          a   b   c    a   b   c
date                                
2015-12-29    1 NaN NaN    0 NaN NaN
2015-12-30  NaN   1 NaN  NaN   1 NaN
2015-12-31  NaN NaN   1  NaN NaN   2
2016-01-01    1 NaN NaN    3 NaN NaN
2016-01-02  NaN   1 NaN  NaN   4 NaN
2016-01-03  NaN NaN   1  NaN NaN   5
```

**EDIT**
This behavior originated in the 0.15.0 update. Prior to that, this was the output:

```
>>> df.groupby(['month', 'date', 'cat1']).sum().unstack()
                    val1          val2        
cat1                   a   b   c     a   b   c
month   date                                  
2015-12 2015-12-29     1 NaN NaN     0 NaN NaN
        2015-12-30   NaN   1 NaN   NaN   1 NaN
        2015-12-31   NaN NaN   1   NaN NaN   2
2016-01 2016-01-01     1 NaN NaN     3 NaN NaN
        2016-01-02   NaN   1 NaN   NaN   4 NaN
        2016-01-03   NaN NaN   1   NaN NaN   5
```

Answer (score 0):

As defined in pandas, grouping with a categorical will always have the full set of categories, even if there isn't any data with that category, e.g., doc example [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#operations)

You can either not use a categorical, or add a `.dropna(how='all')` after your grouping step.

Comment: The dates are expanding, and they are not categoricals. Thanks for the link.